# Complex numbers arithmetic goes wrong

Tags: c++, complex-numbers

Right now I am trying to implement the formula for the probabilities of a [Poisson binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_binomial_distribution#Probability_mass_function).

The formula is the last one in that section, with complex exponentials inside them: 
[image]

I have a very simple code that should do it, but it is outputting wrong probabilities.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    int N=5; //number of coins
    double probabilities[N]={0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1}; //probabilities of coin landing head
    double distr[N+1];
    for (int j=0; j<N+1;j++){
        complex<double> temp1=0.0 + 0.0i;
        for (int k=0; k<N+1;k++){
           for(int l=0;l<N+1;l++){
           complex<double> temp2=1.0 + 0.0i;
               for (int m=0;m<N;m++){
                   temp2=temp2*(1.0+0.0i+(exp(l*2*M_PI*1.0i/(double(N)+1.0))-1.0+0.0i)*probabilities[m]);
               }
               temp2=temp2*exp(l*k*2*M_PI*1.0i/(double(N)+1.0));
               temp1=temp1+temp2/(double(N)+1.0);
           }
        }
        distr[j]=real(temp1);
    }
    for (int i=0;i<N+1;i++){
    cout<< distr[i] << ' ';
  }
```

The output of this code is [1,1,1,1,1,1], which is definitely not correct. I am thinking that maybe I have not been working correctly with complex numbers, but I do not see where I did something wrong. It is frustrating that such a simple program does not work :(.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: subexpressions like the one for `C` are good candidates to be put in a function and be tested in isolation

Comment: NB: exp(i * theta) = cos(theta) + i * sin(theta), and in your case theta = 2π  / (n + 1)

Comment: Unrelated: If you want a nice interface for your distribution function you could look at the standard distributions, like those listed in [<random>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random) to get some ideas.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818  `C` is actually a constant (albeit its value does depend on that initial value of `n`).

Comment: @Alnitak so what? Every piece that can be confirmed to be correct, decreases space for bugs to hide. In the current code I dont see the expression for `C` and wouldnt know how to test for it

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 sure, no reason not to refactor it, but it does only need to be evaluated once, outside the nested loops.   The expression is there in the two assignments to `temp2`, but the OP has those wrong...

Comment: It appears that you are not negating the exponent for the multiplier (the "pow(C, -lk)") bit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code it is clear that `temp1` does not depend on `j`, hence you get the same numbers, the sum over `k`. After you remove the outer loop over `j` and write `distr[k] = real(temp1);` and fix the sign in `exp(l*k*...)`, you'll get the expected result:

```
0.59049 0.32805 0.0729 0.0081 0.00045 1e-05
```

Full code with some simplifications:

```
int main() {
    using namespace std::literals::complex_literals;

    constexpr int N = 5;
    const double probabilities[N] = {.1, .1, .1, .1, .1};
    const auto c = std::exp(2i * M_PI / (N + 1.));

    double distr[N + 1];
    for (int k = 0; k <= N; ++k) {
        auto sum = std::complex<double>(0);
        for(int l = 0; l <= N; ++l) {
            auto prod = std::complex<double>(1);
            for (int m = 0; m < N; ++m)
                prod *= 1. + (std::pow(c, l) - 1.) * probabilities[m];
            sum += prod * std::pow(c, -l * k) / (N + 1.);
        }
        distr[k] = std::real(sum);
    }

    for (auto d : distr)
        std::cout << d << ' ';
}
```